# Redirect SSRS Report When Under Maintenance

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, rdl

I am looking for an easy way to redirect an SSRS report to an "under maintenance" page or report when we have to take a specific report down. Usually, we only take reports down if the back end data gets corrupt, but this happens more than it should. Is there anyway to do this in the report itself using a parameter or on the SharePoint site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could go about this, although none of these would be suitable on a large scale. There's no good way to do this from an administrative perspective.

You could set a filter on the dataset that always returns false so that no records are returned. Then set the `NoRowsMessage` on a table in the report to display the maintenance message.

Another option is to temporarily replace the .rdl file with a standard maintenance message report.

Comment: Thanks @StevenWhite. What I did was replace the file with a temporary RDL, I was just hoping for a better answer. This will do for now.